# How to run previously created Django Project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django. I am using Python 3.7 with Django 2.2.6.

My Django development environment is as the below.

- I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code on a Windows 8.1 computer
- To give the commands I am using 'DOS Command Prompt' & 'Terminal window' in 
  VS Code.
- Created a virtual environment named myDjango
- Created a project in the virtual environment named firstProject
- Created an app named firstApp.

At the first time I could run the project using >python manage.py runserver

Then I had to restart my computer.

- I was able to go inside the previously created virtual environment using
  workon myDjango command.

But my problem is I don't know how to go inside the previously created project 'firstProject' and app 'firstApp' using the 'Command prompt' or using the 'VSCode Terminal window'

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: I think you just have to 'cd' your way into the expected folder where the project(s) are located. I may have misunderstood your goal, if so, please describe more so I can try to help you =)

Comment: @Niknak you are correct! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help out, should I just give that as the final answer and you can accept it? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply navigate to the folder containing the app you want to manage using the command prompt.

The first cd should contain your parent folder.
The second cd should contain the folder that has your current project.
The third cd should be the specific app you want to work on.
After that, you can use the python manage.py to keep working on your app.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is that you just have to guide your way into the correct folder using the command `cd`. As in this example:

```
1. C:\Users\User: cd MainFolder
2. C:\Users\User\MainFolder: cd firstProject
3. C:\Users\User\MainFolder\firstProject: dir (or ls -la for linux, to list all files etc.)
   16-Apr-19  07:14    <DIR>          .
   16-Apr-19  07:14    <DIR>          ..
   15-Apr-19  21:50    <DIR>          .idea
   15-Apr-19  21:43           195,961 firstApp.py

Just a roughly tree structure below to show how it is visualized:

C:
|
|---Main folder
     |
     |---firstProject (if this is your folder)
           |
           |---firstApp (this is your app)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the directory where manage.py file of your Django project is present. It is normally the Base directory of your project.
- In that directory, Press Shift and Right Click at the same time.
- The from the Right Click Menu, Click on "Open PowerShell window here".
- If you have previously frozen the dependencies, you should download them first through requirement.txt file using command:

```
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

- Then run start server command in your PowerShell window.

```
    python manage.py runserver
```

- You will see output like this in PowerShell:

```
    Validating models...

    0 errors found
    November 10, 2019 - 17:36:02
    Django version 1.5, using settings 'my_django15_project.settings'
    Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

- Open the address e.g in above case it is http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your browser, and you will be able to see your project.